# First colums of Form not translated

Tags: forms, translation

I've a problem with my fr_FR translation on CiviCRM 5.20.2. for Wordpress.

On forms, the first colums is not translated and some Yes / No in the second column above image).

[image: Form translation issue]

An idea on the way to slove this issue?

Many thanks by advance!

MG

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: All the admin forms have now been made available for translation but they aren't all in transifex yet because it only has strings up to version 5.22 as of today and the latest changes will be in 5.23. So it may be a few months before they'll be available in transifex for translation.

---

A while ago the admin forms settings started to get moved to a different subsystem, and a note appears to have been made that they should take translation into account (the last bullet point here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/495#note_10020), but if you look in the `<civicrm_root>/settings` you can see that some `title` strings in the files are wrapped in `ts()` but some are not. It is of course ironic that the ones in the localization file are not.

Some of the strings on that page are translated, because they are still handled by the previous system, e.g. Monnaies Disponibles, because it's a fancy multiselect widget.

EDIT: After looking closer at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/translation/blob/master/bin/create-pot-files.sh and the admin screens, it seems like the settings folder isn't included in the files that get scanned. It's just that some strings, like "Recherche de contacts avec autocomplétion" on the search preferences screen, appear to be translated because they are used elsewhere too. So I've posted on the lab ticket to get clarification.

Comment: Hi Demerit !

Many thanks for your answer ! Could you explain me point by point the way to use ts() for those files, and add them to Transitex. If I know the procedure, I can try to translate them.

Regards.

Comment: Actually it looks like it might require more than that. Will update answer.

Comment: Hi !Have you more recent news for this settings translation iisue? Best regards and Happy New Year !

Comment: Yes it's in progress in steps, e.g. here's one step https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16228, and you can follow the lab ticket above. Happy New Year!